# Magento 2.3.1 : A/B testing

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.3.1, testing

I am not sure if this question has been asked before but I badly need to know if AB testing can be set up for Magento 2.3.1 community edition. I know it can be done for Magento 2 enterprise edition but currently we are using the community edition. 
Thank you in advance